# Create alerts using Azure Stream Analytics, Functions, and Notifications Hub

Tags: azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics, azure-notificationhub, azure-alerts

I am working on a project where I have to create alerts on incoming data in Azure Stream Analytics using Azure Functions and Notifications Hub. I would like to know if there is any way using either of these two or all three interfaces to create alerts? What's the main procedure for that?

Also, any possibility of directly notifying/alerting users from Stream Analytics through emails? Without using Azure Functions and Notifications Hub.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: *using Azure Functions and Notifications Hub* why is that? Why not use out of the box monitoring options?

Comment: Out of the box monitoring options such as? Can you please elaborate so I can search about it.

Comment: Using Azure Monitor you can create alerts based on metrics and conditions, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-set-up-alerts

Comment: I followed this but it was asking for a fee when I am creating a condition, I am using Azure free tier portal and I am looking for any free solution (if it exists). Do you know any other method?